# How do I log into a site with WebClient?

Tags: c#, authentication, webclient

I want to download something using a WebClient object in C#, but the download domain requires me to be logged in. How can I log in and keep session data using WebClient? I know how to post data with WebClient.

Comment: What kind of authentication mechanism does the server require? Basic, Forms, Windows/NTLM ?

Comment: lol i solved the problem by adding values maunally via looking from firefox cookies :) webClient.Headers.Add("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=xxxxxxx; mosesuser=xxxxxxx; ");

Comment: Which values? Do you mean the actual auth cookie? Remember, that value will probably expire and cannot be reused at a later time.

Comment: yes i know. so whenever i run the software i will login via firefox and copy paste the cookie :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If the problem you are having is you can authenticate but you cant keep the authentication cookie here is a cookie aware version of WebClient.

```
private class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    { }
    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer c)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = c;
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

        var castRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (castRequest != null)
        {
            castRequest.CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
        }

        return request;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The link you gave me uses forms authentication with HTTP POST, I don't have the time to walk though it but at least it gives you a start with Google.

Comment: i found this. but what do i need to do ? do i have to authenticate  via httpwebrequest or what ?

Comment: It depends on what authentication system the site you are connecting to uses. See some of the other responses on tips for authenticating

Comment: I wish this post would include an example on the actual authentication process itself.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118712/webclient-accessing-page-with-credentials has similar solution, and there is a sample usage code.

Comment: it would have saved me a lot of time if you would have put which namespaces to include in your code example. that's pretty important information to know...

Comment: @Anthony If you type in to google `MSDN WebClient` the first result is [the MSDN page for WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which includes the namespace. For any .NET class just type in `MSDN YourClassName` and the class you are looking for will be within the first 3 links.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at using the [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx) property. E.g. if Basic authentication is used, you will have to set the property to an instance of [NetworkCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) with the proper username and password.

The [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx) pointed to shows how to use the currently logged on user credentials for the request.

Comment: Okey, I see. The server uses Forms authentication. That requires you posting the username and password to the action url specified in the login page html. You must also use a cookie container in order to receive the auth cookie that comes with the response to that post.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG `DoesNotWorkNullReferenceException`