# How can i open a url in web browser (such as IE) and pass credentials

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I want to open a page that required Basic authentication.
I want to pass the Basic authentication header to the browser along with the URL.

How can i do that?

Comment: I am trying do. There are many questions without good response

Comment: okay, so coming to your question, you want to pass the authentication details in the URL?

Comment: afaik, there is no way to do that.

Comment: @Erick Sapir: you can't control the headers a typical browser sends. If you embed a web browser control you may be able to access the headers sent but this does mean you have to distribute your special browser. My answer includes the historical method for embedding credentials in the URL and having these passed as a header.

Comment: If you don't mind using IE from the default WebBrowser control, you can see my answer below, pass the headers and tell it to open in a new window.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Via a header you can:

```
string user = "uuuuuuu";
string pass = "ppppppp";
string authHdr = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user + ":" + pass)) + "\r\n";

webBrowserCtl.Navigate("http://example.com", null, null, authHdr);
```

given that this needs to be done on a per-request basis, an easier option for basic auth is to just;

```
webBrowserCtl.Navigate("http://uuuuuuu:ppppppp@example.com", null, null, authHdr);
```

Comment: I don't want to open it in a web browser object in the application, but in regular browser

Comment: At the end i used your way. It even looks much better.

Comment: How do you obtain the username and password on server side? I mean you are converting to Base64 String. How do I extract the information back?

Comment: Usually via the server variables collection, E.g. `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` in PHP

Answer (score 6):

You could try the old "in URL" format which allowed this but it is insecure:

```
http(s)://username:password@server/resource.ext
```

This exposes credentials and [IE has disabled it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489), but it may still work in other browsers. When this format is used the credentials are available to the browser and it makes the decision to send the basic authentication header depending on how the web server responds.

Comment: Chrome has disabled this functionality as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use something like [`Watin`](http://watin.org/)
[Here](http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/search/label/WatiN) you can find good blog-posts about `Watin`.

The code looks like:

```
public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
{
  using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
  {
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();
  }
}
```

Comment: The Watin link is dead above.  The project can be found on SF at https://sourceforge.net/projects/watin/

Comment: It looks like Watin may be dead too.

Answer (score 0):

First check this code:

```
Dim result As String

Using wClnt As New Net.WebClient

    wClnt.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")

    Using strR As New IO.StreamReader(wClnt.OpenRead("http://ADDRESS_To_READ"))

        result = strR.ReadToEnd

    End Using

End Using
```

If it was not what your where looking for, Check this post, it may help:

[How do I log into a site with WebClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740752/how-to-login-with-webclient-c)

**Update**:

This way *you are not opening any browser*. Just requesting the address you want and passing Credential.

Comment: Thank a lot for down voting all answers!

Comment: That's a moron I rarely see on SO

Comment: I think the downvote was because he wants to do this in a browser rather than in his application. Not that I think your answer isn't a better one.

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser control in .Net uses Internet Explorer as it's browser, so if you don't mind using IE, this is the code I wrote.  ***h5url*** is the url you want to open in a window.  My program doesn't even show a browser control, this is spawns an instance of Internet Explorer with the web page logged in.

```
     using (WebBrowser WebBrowser1 = new WebBrowser())
            {
                String auth =
                    System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_User + ":" + _Password));
                string headers = "Authorization: Basic " + auth + "\r\n";
                WebBrowser1.Navigate(h5URL, "_blank", null, headers);

            }
```

This opens a new browser with any headers you need for authentication, basic or otherwise.