# WebClient accessing page with credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient, credentials, defaultnetworkcredentials

I am trying to access a webpage on a same domain / same asp.net application, that is password protected. Credentials are the same both for webpage firing this call and webpage being accessed.

Here is the code, and I don't know why I always end up with a login form html code?

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.QueryString.Add("ID", "1040"); //add parameters
    //client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    //I tried to add credentials like this
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://domain.loc/testpage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you simply redirecting to that page? Downloading it using code in the server process means you *aren't* using the same credentials. If I understand correctly, rather than the browser (with the client's credentials) accessing the page, a different process on a different machine (the server) is downloading it and presenting it to the client!

Comment: How are those credentials provided to the web page? Does it use Forms Authentication?

Comment: @shambulator What do you mean by redirect to that page? I am trying to get html code of that page.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Yes, it uses Forms authentication.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I suspect that the web page that you are trying to access uses Forms Authentication. This means that you will have to provide a valid authentication cookie if you want to be able to access protected resources. And in order to obtain a valid authentication cookie you will have to first authenticate yourself by sending a POST request to the LogOn page which emits the cookie. Once you retrieve the cookie you will be able to send it along on subsequent requests on protected resources. You should also note that out of the box `WebClient` doesn't support cookies. For this reason you could write a custom cookie aware web client:

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Now you could use this client to fire off the 2 requests:

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "username", "john" },
        { "password", "secret" },
    };
    client.UploadValues("http://domain.loc/logon.aspx", values);

    // If the previous call succeeded we now have a valid authentication cookie
    // so we could download the protected page
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://domain.loc/testpage.aspx");
}
```

Obviously due to the ViewState crapiness of ASP.NET you might need to send a couple of other parameters along your logon request. Here's what you could do: authenticate in a web browser and look with FireBug the exact parameters and headers that need to be sent.

Comment: Solution looks nice and clean. Should names for login collection really be username and password? And is there a different way for application to use current credentials despite the fact that is form based auth.?

Comment: @John, I don't know if names for login should be username and password. That would entirely depend on how your Logon page is implemented and what parameters it expects. And, no, there isn't other way. You need to obtain a valid forms authentication cookie and the only way to obtain such cookie is by providing correct credentials to your logon page. It is only this page (hopefully :-)) that emits forms authentication cookies.

Comment: code does not work, but I understand the idea, and I will try to get it to work.

Comment: could not get it to work. I am now thinking that WebClient is not the way to go..

Comment: WebClient is the way to go. Actually you could use an HttpWebRequest (which is what WebClient uses under the covers) to send an HTTP request to the server but you will have to write far more code. You are saying that you cannot get it to work but in the same time you are not providing enough information so that we can help you. So all we could do right now is wish you good luck.

Comment: I found a solution that combines login data, submit button and viewstate. You might want to take a look at this link http://odetocode.com/Articles/162.aspx and share your comment with us