# Can you supply Credentials through Webclient in C#?

Tags: c#, cas

I need to access a php page that's behind a central authentication server. Using any other means, when I try to access this site, it redirects to the CAS page, awaiting authentication. Which essentially, has me supplying `GET` variables to the authentication page. (do not want.) Unfortunately, we cannot remove the CAS for this page, because it is a massive security risk.

So my question is, is there anyway to supply the credentials I have to the CAS, store any cookies from that, then using that, access the php page?

my attempt below:

Since I'm using the `GET` method, I don't need to worry about waiting until I'm at the php page to supply the values, I just need to actually access the page, which we'll call `https://site.com/page.php?var1=value1&var2=value2`

As [WebClient accessing page with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118712/webclient-accessing-page-with-credentials) suggested, I created a class `CookieAwareClient`

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
}
```

and then the following to submit:

using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        {"username", "usr" },
        {"password", "(passw0rd!)"}, //don't worry. not actual information
    };

    //This should bring me to the login page, which will upload the values I have given
    client.UploadValues("https://site.com/page.php?var1=value1&var2=value2", values);

    string result = client.DownloadString("https://site.com/page.php?var1=value1&var2=value2");
```

unfortunately, this still does not log me into the CAS, and result is returned as the HTML for the CAS.

Does anyone have ANY idea how I fix this? thank you for your help.

Comment: care to share the website ?

Comment: Not that I am suspicious of anyone on stack overflow, but I fear it might break my NDA to do so.

Comment: its ok, rules are imp !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if CAS supports standard HTTP auth out of the box. It is generally forms based.

After being redirected to CAS, you'll want to parse/scrape the page for a few of the hidden form variables. POST those parameters, the username, and the password (along with the cookie that was returned with GET request).

CAS should return an HTTP redirect. (There will be an additional cookie added to the collection: CASTGC cookie.) The webclient should redirect you back to the originally requested resource. Some apps might need two hops to get back.

If you will be polling the resource within the lifetime of the web application's session,  make the subsequent calls using the same CookieCollection and you shouldn't have authenticate against CAS again.