# Using Cookie aware WebClient

Tags: c#, cookies, webclient

I'm using [this enhanced version of WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118712/webclient-accessing-page-with-credentials) to login in a site:

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
        public CookieAwareWebClient()
        {
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
            request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
            return request;
        }
}
```

And this way I send cookie to the site:

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "username", "john" },
        { "password", "secret" },
    };
    client.UploadValues("http://example.com//dl27929", values);

    // If the previous call succeeded we now have a valid authentication cookie
    // so we could download the protected page
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://domain.loc/testpage.aspx");
}
```

But when I run my program and capture the traffic in Fiddler I get 302 status code. I tested the request in Fiddler this way and everything is OK and I get the status code of 200.
The request in the Fiddler:

```
GET http://example.com//dl27929 HTTP/1.1
Cookie: username=john; password=secret;
Host: domain.loc
```

And here is the request sending by the application:

```
POST http://example.com//dl27929 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: www.domain.loc
Content-Length: 75
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

As you can see it doesn't send the cookie.
Any idea?

Comment: You never set the cookie, UploadValues does not apply the value collection to the cookies. Also your "working program" is doing a `GET` which would be one of the `DownloadXxxxx` methods not a Upload method.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain How can I set the cookie?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I would start with one of the [`client.CookieContainer.Add(`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.CookieContainer.Add(v=vs.110).aspx) methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works fine, just I forgot to set the cookie, Thanks [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain):

```
client.CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri("http://example.com//dl27929"), "username=john; password=secret;");
```