# Connecting to REST API using HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use VB.net to connect to a REST API using HTTP Basic Authentication. The authentication succeeds but subsequent requests still yield a `401 error`, what am I missing?

```
Dim Client As New WebClient
Client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user","password")

' Works and authenticates
MsgBox(Client.DownloadString("http://example.site/api/login"))

' Returns 401
MsgBox(Client.DownloadString("http://example.site/api/helloworld"))
```

I should add, if I go to `/api/login` and authenticate in a browser, I can then request `/api/helloworld` correctly - so the error is client side.

Comment: The site probably sends a *cookie* after authentication which you are supposed to return on subsequent requests. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/11118712/87698

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim credentials As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user" & ":" & "password"))
Client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization) = String.Format("Basic {0}", credentials)
```