# Login to website with WebRequest

Tags: vb.net, post, authentication, httpwebrequest

VB2012: I'm trying to login to my company website to parse out some info. It has a typical page

> portal.mycompany.com

which redirects eventually to

> security.mycompany.com/login.jsp?TYPE=xxx&METHOD=GET&{more parameters}

and there we are presented with textboxes for user name and password. I have Fiddler running and am a little lost as to what to look for when setting up my POST. My example looks to be the same from various coding sites. I am mainly looking for help on what to look for in Fiddler to use as a basis for the POST request to login to my site programmatically.

I took a look at some of the Fiddler entries and added what I thought was the enrty with the credentials. But when i tried adding this to the POST request it just responded with the original page.

```
    Dim cookieJar As New Net.CookieContainer()
    Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse
    Dim strURL As String

    Try
        'Get Cookies
        strURL = "http://portal.mycompany.com"
        request = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3"
        request.Method = "GET"
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar
        response = request.GetResponse()

        For Each tempCookie As Net.Cookie In response.Cookies
            cookieJar.Add(tempCookie)
        Next

        'Send the post data now
        request = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3"
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar

        Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
        writer.Write("email=username&pass=password") 'where do I get this in Fiddler?
        writer.Close()
        response = request.GetResponse()

        'Get the data from the page
        Dim stream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim data As String = stream.ReadToEnd()
        response.Close()

        If data.Contains("<title>MyCompany") = True Then
            'LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Does Fiddler state that you authenticate with a POST request? Your example URI suggests otherwise: `...&METHOD=GET&...`

Comment: Not being a Fiddler expert, what would I look for? I see maybe like 15 entries after I click on the Login button.

Comment: You need to find the request in the list that actually includes your username/password. Then under request headers it should say either `GET /someurl HTTP/1.1` or `POST /someurl HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: OK Out of all the entries I see one with my credentials and the header has a POST /site/logform/log.ddd HTTP/1.1. Now here I am theorizing I look at TextView and use the entry there as my addition to the request?

Comment: Yes. You'll also have to change your code to send the `POST` request to `/site/logform/log.ddd`, too

Comment: There are a few posts related to your problem in C#, are you interested in seeing those? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4740851/2455159 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118712/webclient-accessing-page-with-credentials may get you started if you are willing to 'translate' to VB.