# Retrieve values from existing open tab in Chrome using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, console-application

I am trying to build a console application using c# .net.. I need one particular functionality which is to retrieve values from an external website. The thing is we need to sign in to that website. I am able to open the page that i need using process.start in chrome signed in with the values i need.. but problem is when retrieving the value from page.. i thought of getting source code but every way i try it does not take the session and hence i am getting just error page source code as i am just entering the URL n not accessing the already opened tab? Is there any other way available either using JavaScript or c#?

Comment: you can use either htmlagilitypack for this (which is great), or selenium webdriver. I can recommend both and use them daily for both scraping and testing. (in your case, probably selenium is the best fit as you need session and javascript functionality) -https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver quick tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1016775/Getting-Started-with-WebDriver-Csharp-in-Minutes

Answer (score 1):

Use WebClient API to login and download page data. You will need to make it cookie aware in order to maintain session. You will need to add reference to System.Web Assembly to use this API in console application.

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Now use it like

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "username", "john" },
        { "password", "secret" },
    };
    client.UploadValues("http://domain.loc/logon.aspx", values);

    // If the previous call succeeded we now have a valid authentication cookie
    // so we could download the protected page
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://domain.loc/testpage.aspx");
}
```

I borrowed this piece of code from [WebClient accessing page with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118712/webclient-accessing-page-with-credentials)