# C# security, Scheduled Task/Windows Service, use one user for web calls, another for DB updates

Tags: c#, windows, security, service

I have a scheduled task to create to get data from a site using the webclient 
class. How do I execute a database update with the data retrieved under a different windows user? I was told not to use the same account to access the site as performs the update. Should I just create a windows service that runs the web request then call a db component with authentication settings set under IIS to run under a different user? Or is there a tidier way to do this running a single exe as a scheduled task? The Scheduled task runs under a single user. Could I run the task and switch user for the update? We are using Windows authentication at the database level.

Answer (score 1):

Run two Windows Services. One to get the data from the website, running under Account "A" which stores the data locally. The other Windows Service running under Account "B" picks up the locally stored data and executes the database update.

Other designs will require you to store the credentials somewhere in a config or other file - this way the Windows Services are always running under the correct account for the task they are attempting.

Comment: Thanks for that. Having two services is fine but ideally I would like to perform an update after the Web request and log whether the retrieval was successful. Otherwise the first service must log to a text file while the other checks to see which files have been downloaded and which have failed. A single service is tidier if possible. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly stated that you will have to use a Windows user to get access to the database. However, often this will not be the case when you authenticate against a web site so exactly how you solve your problem will depend on the details of that.

You should probably execute your process as the Windows user that has access to the database. Then you have to solve how to authenticate against the web site. If the site uses forms based authentication it is a bit complicated but there is an answer to the question [WebClient accessing page with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118861/98607) that might help.

If you need to use the [`WebClient.Credentials`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx) property to authenticate against the web site you might find it easier to execute your process as the user that has access to the web site. You then need to use impersonation to access the database. A simple way to do that is to use the [SimpleImpersonation](https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation) NuGet package.

In most cases you will have to store the password for one of the users so your process can use it to either log in to the web site or impersonate the user. A relatively safe way to store the password is to use the [Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx). The class [ProtectedData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) can assist you in storing secrets so only a specific user on the computer can access the secret (e.g. the password).