# C# WinForms - Using WebClient to fill form elements on authenticated page and submit them

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

Using the best answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118712/webclient-accessing-page-with-credentials), I could successfully submit a login form and get an authenticated webpage using WebClient:

```
    var loginCredentials = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "username", "user123" },
        { "password", "pass321" },
    };

    client.UploadValues(
        @"http://www.mywebsite.com/User/Login?ReturnUrl=" +
        @"http://www.mywebsite.com/Tickets/Search", loginCredentials);
```

However, when I try submitting another form to search for specific filters (one is a "dropdown" element and the other is an "option" element) on the resulting webpage, I get a webexception on the method UploadValues:

```
    var jitbitSearch = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "fromUserId_username", "447" },
        { "statusId", "-3" },
    };

    try
    {
        client.UploadValues(
        @"http://www.mywebsite.com/Tickets/Search", jitbitSearch);
    }
    catch {}

    string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.mywebsite.com/Tickets/Search");
    textBox1.Text = result;
```

HTML output of **fromUserId_username** (dropdown):

```
    <td><script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>   <input type="text" id="fromUserId_username" name="fromUserId_username" value="" placeholder="Email or user" />
<input type="hidden" id="fromUserId" name="fromUserId" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        InitUserBox('fromUserId', "");
    });
</script>
```

HTML output of **statusId** (select option):

```
<td>Status:</td>
<td><select name="statusId">
        <option value=""></option>
                <option value="10"  >Undergoing</option>
                <option value="5"  >Under analysis</option>
                <option value="2"  >Pending</option>
                <option value="6"  >On hold</option>
                <option value="3"  >Closed</option>
                <option value="1"  >Under testing</option>
                <option value="4"  >New</option>
                <option value="7"  >Under development</option>
                <option value="8"  >Recurring</option>
            <option value="">--------</option>
                <option value="-10"  style="color:#CC6666;">(not) Undergoing</option>
                <option value="-5"  style="color:#CC6666;">(not) Under analysis</option>
                <option value="-2"  style="color:#CC6666;">(not) Pending</option>
                <option value="-6"  style="color:#CC6666;">(not) On hold</option>
                <option value="-3"  style="color:#CC6666;">(not) Closed</option>
                <option value="-1"  style="color:#CC6666;">(not) Under testing</option>
                <option value="-4"  style="color:#CC6666;">(not) New</option>
                <option value="-7"  style="color:#CC6666;">(not) Under development</option>
                <option value="-8"  style="color:#CC6666;">(not) Recurring</option>
    </select>
```

Any idea what's causing the exception? Is it because the method UploadValues doesn't support this kind of input? Thanks.

*Note: Even if I comment out one of the form inputs, both of them trigger the webexception.*

EDIT: The exception I'm getting is the following:
"*The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error*".

Comment: _"I get a webexception"_ - can you edit your question to include details of the exception, including any inner exceptions.

Comment: @stuartd Updated!

Comment: Is it your website, or a third party one?

Comment: @stuartd It's a third party helpdesk solution by Jitbit.

Comment: Inspecting the actual network traffic using Fiddler may help.

Comment: I have done similar things many times, sometimes there are hidden fields that are filled (via javascript) when submit button is clicked. Just use the network tab of the google chrome (in inspect element) so see the list of data is being posted. it will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question, doing this small change worked for me:

```
byte[] request = client.UploadValues(@"http://www.mywebsite.com/Tickets/Search", "POST", jitbitSearch);
string req = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(request);
textBox1.Text = req;
```