# Creating a method that uses WebBrowser and returns HTML?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

How do you create a method that does this:
Login to a website, then read a (member-only) page and return the HTML.

I came up with this (which obviously doesn't work because I don't know how to make it return the page content)

```
public string LoginAndReadPage() {
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
    wb.Navigate("hxxp://mysite.com/login");
}

private async void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (wb.Url.ToString().Contains("login"))
    {
        wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("email")[0].SetAttribute("value", _login);
        wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("password")[0].SetAttribute("value", _password);
        wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")[0].InvokeMember("click");
    }
    else if (wb.Url.ToString().Contains("dashboard"))
    {
        return wb.DocumentText; // I want to return the content of mysite.com/dashboard
    }
    else
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); //wait for 1 second just to let the WB catch up
        wb.Navigate("hxxp://mysite.com/dashboard");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `wb.Document` is the DOM what else do you want?

Comment: @Edmad: I want to return it, probably from LoginAndReadPage method

Comment: Do you have to use web browser control?

Comment: @Niklas No, do you have another solution? (The web page uses AngularJS to load the content and OAuth)

Comment: Im not familiar with that, though check and see if this works? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118712/webclient-accessing-page-with-credentials

Comment: Thanks Niklas, it is definitely related but looks a lot more complicated than using a WebBrowser (although I never use WebBrowser either) and I don't think WebClient handles AJAX-loaded content

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is called "scraping" or sometimes "webscraping". It's a big topic so I'd recommend [googling it](https://www.google.at/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23+scraping&*).

Potentially you could use something like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) via the C# Driver to do this as well. Selenium was designed for automated UI testing but it definitely has all the tools you need to do what you want.