# C# The remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized

Tags: c#

I am trying to download a xml file from an url but I get this error:
"The remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized". Also, this webpage needs some credentials.

I searched on different topics before coming to ask you, but I didn't find a solution to this...

Here are two versions of codes I tried but didn't work:

```
try
{
    WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
    wClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(nni, pwd);
    var dlString = wClient.DownloadString(url);
    //Stream data = wClient.OpenRead(url);
    //var reader = new XmlTextReader(wClient.OpenRead(url));
    //doc.LoadXml();
    doc.Load(wClient.OpenRead(url));
    Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerText);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

---

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(xmlUrl);
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(nni, pwd);
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(xmlUrl);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

}
```

Can you guys please help me on this?

Comment: it depends on the kind of authentication the `url` is using

Comment: do you know the authentication type? "basic" or "bearer" or something else?

Comment: You can use Fiddler or similar to see the response headers. Which can help you get an answer to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebClient accessing page with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118712/webclient-accessing-page-with-credentials)

Comment: @Alex & Neville Nazerane:I 'm not sure about the authentification type, maybe by proxy... When I go to the url a dialog box appears, asking for credentials.

Comment: @Bernard Vander Beken: I tried my code on .Net Fiddle and get this error "The remote name could not be resolved: 'myDomain'"

Comment: without knowing what authentication type it's using, you won't be able to authenticate

Comment: @Alex, how can I check what the type is?

Comment: ask the owner of the service you are calling

Comment: I will ask and give you the answer

Comment: The problem is solved. Finally, I noticed that I was querying the wrong server. Thanks for your time and help!