# profile.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated return false nobody helped me

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, api, web-services

i'm trying to connect a web service build with another project(c#) to my project(asp.net mvc). currently i can login and logout but i cannot bring the query to my project because the profile.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated it return false.

here is how i call the login query and another query to bring some information. both of them work when i connect using the web browser. the problem is about the identity.

***MY PROJECT***

```
//LOGIN USING WEBSERVICE
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel _login)
    {

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json"); //Content-Type  
            client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");
            string result = 
 client.DownloadString("http://localhost/Services/BlueLifeDataService.svc/Login?login='" + 
 _login.db + "\\" + _login.Username + "'&password='" + _login.Password + "'");
            var _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
            if(_result["d"]["Login"].Value == true)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Append("User", _login.Username);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }

    //BRING QUERY 
    public  IActionResult Get()
    
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json"); //Content-Type  
            client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");
            string result = 
 client.DownloadString("http://localhost/Services/BlueLifeDataService.svc/Aircraft?");
            var _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);

            return View();
          
        }

    }
```

THE WEBSERVICE IN C#

```
 public class BlueLifeDataService : DataService<BlueLifeEntities>
 {
    private CommonProfile profile = new CommonProfile();

    /**
    // To call http://localhost:81/Services/BlueLifeDataService.svc/GetTechLog?id=3810L do 
  this
    [DataContract]
    class TechLogDTO 
    {
        public TechLogDTO() 
        {
        }

        [DataMember]
        public long idTechlog { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string sPilot { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string sRemark { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string sAircraftReg { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string sTLNumber { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public EntityCollection<CRS> CRS { get; set; }
        public EntityCollection<Files> Files { get; set; }
        public EntityCollection<FlightsAirframe> FlightsAirframe { get; set; }
    }

    //To call http://localhost:81/Services/BlueLifeDataService.svc/GetTechLog?id=3810L do this
    [WebGet]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetTechLog?id={id}", Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = 
  WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string GetTechLog(long id)
    {
        string json;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new 
  DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TechLogDTO));
            TechLog e = this.CurrentDataSource.TechLog.FirstOrDefault(t => t.idTechlog == id);
            ser.WriteObject(ms, new TechLogDTO 
            { 
                idTechlog = e.idTechlog, 
                sAircraftReg = e.sAircraftReg,
                sTLNumber = e.sTLNumber,
                sPilot = e.sPilot,
                sRemark = e.sRemark,
                CRS = e.CRS,
                Files = e.Files,
                FlightsAirframe = e.FlightsAirframe
            });
            json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, 
  Convert.ToInt16(ms.Length));
        }

        return json;
    }
    */


   #region Configuration

    // Cette méthode n'est appelée qu'une seule fois pour initialiser les stratégies au niveau 
   des services.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: définissez des règles pour indiquer les jeux d'entités et opérations de 
   service visibles, pouvant être mis à jour, etc.
        // Exemples :
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;

        config.UseVerboseErrors = 
   bool.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("UseVerbose"));
        config.SetEntitySetPageSize("TechLog", 
   int.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("TechLogEntitiesPerPage")));
    }

    protected override BlueLifeEntities CreateDataSource()
    {
        if (profile.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string connection =
                DBConnectionString.GetEntityConnectionString(profile.DataBase, 
   "Datasets.BlueLife.BlueLifeModel");

            var context = new BlueLifeEntities(connection)
            {
                CommandTimeout = 
   int.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("SQLCommandTimeout"))
            };

            return context;
        }

        return base.CreateDataSource();
    }

     [WebGet]
    public bool Login(string login, string password)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(login, password) &&
            ServiceAuthHeaderValidation.HasAccessToApplication(login.Split('\\')[0], 
 "BlueLifeServiceSoapClient"))
        {
            if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(login, "iPhone") & !Roles.IsUserInRole(login, "Client"))
                return false;

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login, false);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }


    [WebGet]
    public bool Logout()
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Operations

    [WebGet]
    public void UpdateFollowingNewTechLog(string aircraftRegistration)
    {
        if (!profile.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("You're not authenticated. Please, Log in!");

        var lastTL = (from t in this.CurrentDataSource.TechLog
                      where t.sAircraftReg == aircraftRegistration
                      orderby t.idTechlog descending
                      select t).FirstOrDefault();

        var countersToUpdate = (from c in this.CurrentDataSource.Counter
                                where c.sAircraftReg == aircraftRegistration
                                select c.idCounter).ToList();

        var crewMembersToUpdate = this.CurrentDataSource.FlightCrew.Where(fc => fc.idPilot != 
 null &&
            fc.FlightsAirframe.TechLog.idTechlog == lastTL.idTechlog).OrderByDescending(fc => 
 fc.idFlightCrew)
            .Select(fc => fc.idPilot).Distinct().ToList();

        var plannedDutiesToUpdate = this.CurrentDataSource.CrewDuty.Where(cd => cd.idPilot != 
 null &&
            cd.idTechlog == lastTL.idTechlog).OrderByDescending(cd => cd.idCrewDuty)
            .Select(cd => cd.idPilot).Distinct().ToList();

    #region Interceptor

    [QueryInterceptor("Aircraft")]
    public Expression<Func<Aircraft, bool>> OnQueryAircraft()
    {
        string login = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["login"]; 
        string password = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["password"];
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(login) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            bool result = Login(login, password);
            if(result)
            {
                return (Aircraft a) => PersonalFleet.Contains(a.sAircraftReg);
            }
            else
            {
                return (Aircraft a) => false;
            }
        }

      
        // Loged in user in this project + Calling from other project
        if (!profile.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return (Aircraft a) => false;
        }

        return (Aircraft a) => PersonalFleet.Contains(a.sAircraftReg);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in your project code, you are creating a new WebClient in the Get action, but you are not passing in the FormsAuthentication cookie that you received in the Login action when you make your call to the Web Service - so it cannot authenticate that request. You might want to take a look at: [WebClient accessing page with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118712/webclient-accessing-page-with-credentials)