# Send url with web client

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

When I tried to the following link url on address bar, response is "OK"

```
http://ww.exmaple.com.tr/webservices/addlead.php?first_name=" + r.Name + "&last_name=" + r.Surname + "&phone=" + r.Telephone + "&hash=" + r.HashCode
```

But when I tried to link with webclient like the below, response is "AUTH ERROR"

```
string URI = "http://ww.exmaple.com.tr/webservices/addlead.php";
string myParameters = "first_name=" + r.Name + "&last_name=" + r.Surname + "&phone=" + r.Telephone + "&hash=" + r.HashCode;

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
  wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you shall use rather DownloadString instead of UploadString(URI, myParameters) like this:

```
string URI = "http://ww.exmaple.com.tr/webservices/addlead.php?";
string myParameters = "first_name=" + r.Name + "&last_name=" + r.Surname + "&phone=" + r.Telephone + "&hash=" + r.HashCode;

URI += myParameters;

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
 try
 {
  wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  string HtmlResult = wc.DownloadString(URI);
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
  // handle error
  MessageBox.Show( ex.Message );
 }
}
```

And when you want to open an URL needed authorization, you must maybe do it twice:

- first with GET just to open a session and get a cookie
- after that with POST using the cookie from step 1

[EDITED] Found the example for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4740851/1758762

Good luck!