# Navigate to page and click a button

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
 Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";
 p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = "www.yandex.ru";
 p.Start();
```

After the call to `p.Start()` I need to simulate pressing a button on that page. How can I do this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Do you have to use internet explorer (for example you are loading a flash object or the site has some kind of ActiveX control) or can you just use a [WebClient that supports cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740752/how-to-login-with-webclient-c-sharp/4740851#4740851)?

Comment: Thank you all guys. I am glad that your helped. I will try. Once again, thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run c:\program files\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe or whatever your browser path is and then pass the URL as an argument into the process.start function.

For example

```
   Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", "http://www.yandex.ru/");
```

Comment: You are not completely understood. This my code.                 Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "www.yandex.ru";
            p.Start(); But I need to click on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [WatIN](http://watin.org/) which will help you automate all major HTML elements.

**Example**

The following example illustrates how to use WatiN to click on a button on a specific page according to its `id` attribute

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var _IExplore = new WatiN.Core.IE("http://www.yandex.ru"))
    {
        // _IExplore.Button(WatiN.Core.Find.ByName("nameOfButton")).Click(); //Clicks the button according to its name attribute
        _IExplore.Button(WatiN.Core.Find.ById("idOfButton")).Click(); //Clicks the button according to its id attribute
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Internet Explorer COM connection.  [For example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43491/Opening-IE-Using-C-and-Firing-Events).  And as @Hans Passant mentioned above, [here is the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you all guys. I am glad that your helped. I will try. Once again, thank you all :)