# WCF data service client connect using session

Tags: c#, session, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF data service on my asp.net website that looks like:

```
public class WcfDataService : DataService<MyEntities>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {            
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);           
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }

    protected override Data.Sub.TcSubEntities CreateDataSource()
    {

        // if user is logged in enable him to query database otherwise do not
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] != null)
        {
            return base.CreateDataSource();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

My client first calls the page *myDomain.com/Authenticate.aspx* then I set `HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]` equal to the id of the user.

Anyways the client is a console application and I have set a reference to that data service. The way I want to query the database is like:

```
var db = new ServiceReference.MyEntities(new Uri("MyDomain/WcfDataService.svc"));
var customers = db.Customers.ToList();
```

I use **[How do I log into a site with WebClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740752/how-do-i-log-into-a-site-with-webclient)** In order to be able to access pages on my website. **how could I use that webclient to connect to my wcf data service so that I could use the same session?**

PS

If I have the session id could I pass that through the url as a parameter?

Comment: If i remember correctly you can pass it through the url if your session is setup not to use cookies. Otherwise you have to put the session id into a cookie and add it to your request via the headers to pass on the session id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. I manage how to add cookies to the request. On the client I did:

Note I am using a cookie aware webclient from: [Using CookieContainer with WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1777221/637142)

```
var cookieAwareWebClient= //.... authenticate 

var db = new ServiceReference.MyEntities(new Uri("MyDomain/WcfDataService.svc"));

db.SendingRequest += ( s,  arg) =>
{                
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = arg.Request as HttpWebRequest;
    httpRequest.CookieContainer = cookieAwareWebClient.CookieContainer;   // I made that property public                             
};

var myUsers = db.Users.ToList();
```